# Localized settings bundle

Tags: ios, localization, ios5.1, settings.bundle, localizable.strings

My application's languages are English and German.
I have localized my settings bundle to German.

One of my pages (int the Settings.app) includes topics.
I have added them in the settings.bundle in an English alphabetical order (Topics.plist).
I have Topics.strings which translates every topic to German. Of course the order of the topics remain as in English, which is not correct.

Is there a way to fix it?

**EDIT:**
I need some way to read this plist into an array, sort it, and return it back to the settings.bundle. I am not sure if I can write directly to Settings.bundle.

The line:
    BOOL success = [dict writeToFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]     pathForResource:@"Settings.bundle/Topics" ofType:@"plist"] atomically:YES];

This line returns YES on iPhone 4S 5.1.1 and NO on iPhone 5 6.0.2.
I guess Apple fixed this in iOS6, am I correct?

Please help me solve my problem and make the topics in the Settings.bundle appear alphabetically sorted both in English and in German.

Thanks!

Comment: Anyone? Nobody has ever done this before?

Answer (score 2):

When you load the topics from the bundle into an array, then sort them alphabetically before using them as the data source for your table.
See [this code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/InternationalMountains/Listings/Classes_RootViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008756-Classes_RootViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_8) for an example.

Comment: You mean load the topics from the settings.bundle into an array, sort them and then write them back to the settings.bundle?

Comment: the example you referenced does not show how to localize an NSDictionary of topics inside the Settings.bundle. I am still unable to solve it. I want the topics appear sorted in my Settings bundle in both languages! Can someone please provide me a piece of code to accomplish that?

Comment: The code example shows, how to sort alphabetically. I assumed, that you load the appropriate settings.bundle (that, for the current language) into an array or dictionary and use this as the data source for your tableview. You don't have to write it back; you work on a array, not the bundle.

Comment: OK, I will repeat the scenario I am in. I have topics in the Settings.bundle (which is located in Topics.plist) and they are translated according to Topics.strings. The translation works well, but the they do not appear sorted alphabetically IN THE SETTINGS.BUNDLE. I do not have a tableview. I need them the topics to be translated and appear sorted in the Settings.app.

Comment: Edited my question to more clarification of my needs